# Ruby: How to use regex to see if string is in date format with dashes?

Tags: ruby

I want to see if the string I passed is in YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
string = "2013-03-02"
string[/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{4}/] #why does it return nil?
```

I want to check that there are 4 digits, followed by a dash, followed by 2 digits, followed by a dash, followed by 2 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{4}` should be `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` as per your wish.

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> string = "2013-03-02"
=> "2013-03-02"
>> string[/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/]
=> "2013-03-02"
>> string = "2013-03-2"
=> "2013-03-2"
>> string[/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/]
=> nil
```

Comment: @Edmund happened with every one.. when too much concentration happened. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "2013-03-02"
=> "2013-03-02"
irb(main):002:0> str[/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/]
=> "2013-03-02"
```

Your last `\d{4}` needs to be a `\d{2}`. I love http://rubular.com/ for testing regex in Ruby.